# WCDN cache policy in the http response header

Tags: django, caching

I deployed a django project on a server, and have some unexpected cache of data on http response. some of my pages should have changed after adding some data in the panel, but it's changing after a while.
here is my response header:

```
WCDN-Cache-Policy: SMART 
WCDN-CacheID: ...
```

I use nginx, gunicorn and supervisor on my server.
How can I disable this cache system?

Answer (score 0):

Your website is behind a cache server and these headers sent by the cache server. contact your hosting provider for more information.